# MySQL NOT REGEXP not working when excluding results

Tags: mysql, regex

I only want rows which do not contain any of the words matched in the REGEXP but somehow it's not working properly.

I found this as an alternative not to have 20 lines of

```
AND user_agent NOT LIKE 'word'
```

But my REGEXP seems broken, this is the line:

```
AND user_agent NOT REGEXP '/(ligatus|googlebot|appengine|Mediapartners-Google|semrushbot|ipad|iphone|android|admantx|MJ12bot|CCBot|bingbot|HybridBot|crawler)/gmi'
```

Comment: Remove `/(` and `)/gmi`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew why did you not do it as answer since it's the good answer? :D

Comment: thanks! that was.. really simple. But I need the /i for a case insensitive match. Can I still add it anyhow?

Comment: @Mike - For Case Insensitive, have the collation of `user_agent` be something ending with `_ci`.  (Let's see `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the comments have pointed out, you have a slight syntax problem in your `REGEXP` expression.  But, in addition to this, you should surround the alternation with word boundaries, because you want to match/non match entire words, but not words which might appear as substrings.

```
WHERE user_agent NOT REGEXP '[[:<:]](ligatus|googlebot|appengine)[[:>:]]'
```

I only included the first three terms so that it would fit in a single line, but you may use the full alternation.